# Почему этот код работает?

Tags: php, mysql

Я хотел узнать как получить все строки таблицы поочередно в массив и нашел следующее решение:

```
$q = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table');
$res = array();
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
$res[] = $r;
}

print_r($res);
```

Однако здесь я вижу лишь что мы:
1 получаем массив строк из бд,
2 начинаем считывать строку массива циклом
while
3 ???
4 заканчивается считывание и на выходе имеется готовый массив.

Почему вместо бесконечного считывания одной строки код переходит автоматом к следующим, несмотря на то что счётчика нету? Это аналог foreach? Как это работает?

Comment: Потому, что при каждом вызове `mysql_fetch_assoc` происходит переход к следующей строке результата

Comment: ... и если мы переходим в конец массива, то он возвращает false, да? Вас понял, спасибо!

Comment: @Михаил Акимов while() не аналог форича. Он выполняется покуда результат вычисления выражения в его скобках  истинен. При каждой итерации происходит смещение внутреннего указателя массива, и когда достигнут конец массива, выражение в скобках цикла возвращает false, что и означает для цикла while() конец всех итераций.

Comment: @Эдуард, вы правы, while - не аналог foreach, однако именно в комбинации с данной функцией (fetch_assoc) мы получаем тот же эффект [проходимся по всем элементам массива]

Comment: @Михаил Акимов если рассуждать подобным образом, то и для for() можно создать _комбинацию_ , которая заставит его отработать так же, как и foreach().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

> Возвращает ассоциативный массив, соответствующий полученному ряду **и
>   сдвигает вперед внутренний указатель результата.**

Также обратите внимание, что расширение `mysql` уже очень давно не поддерживается, а в PHP 7 вообще удалено. Используйте [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php) или [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: а если к примеру на сервере установлен php5 или php4 , тоже не будет поддерживаться ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский PHP5(в котором расширение объявлено устаревшим) прекратил развитие 19 января 2017 года. Патчи безопасности будут выходить до 19 января 2018 (и только для 5.6). Про php4 вообще забудьте.